# Reduce Size of SYSAUX

Tags: oracle

I am trying to reduce the size of our SYSAUX Table.  Currently the largest four occupants are below.  As you can see it is mostly the Server Manageability items.

```sql
select occupant_desc, space_usage_kbytes
  from v$sysaux_occupants
  where space_usage_kbytes > 0 order by space_usage_kbytes desc
/
```

```
OCCUPANT_DESC                                       SPACE_USAGE_KBYTES     
Server Manageability - Advisor Framework                4613440    
Server Manageability - Optimizer Statistics History     2522944    
Server Manageability - Automatic Workload Repository    1457280    
Enterprise Manager Repository                       172480
```

I have reduced retention to 7 days

```sql
select dbms_stats.get_stats_history_retention from dual;
```

```
GET_STATS_HISTORY_RETENTION
---------------------------
                          7
```

I have purged statistics older than 7 days:

```sql
exec DBMS_STATS.PURGE_STATS(SYSDATE-7);
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

All this but no luck reducing space in the tablespace.  I also tried following the instructions in [Purging statistics from the SYSAUX tablespace](http://jhdba.wordpress.com/2009/05/19/purging-statistics-from-the-sysaux-tablespace/)   but the space is still full.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You don't mention your version but if you are using 11g Automatic SQL Plan Management you may be hitting a bug that allows its entried in SYSAUX to grow... a lot... details here http://juliandontcheff.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/a-friend-in-need-is-a-friend-to-avoid-should-i-set-optimizer_capture_sql_plan_baselinestrue/

Comment: reducing the size of objects in a tablespace will not reduce the size of the tablespace automatically - see [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/15348/1396)

Answer (score 1):

Try moving some objects into another tablespace. 
Documentation on this is quite confusing, referring to an uncertain pl/sql procedure, that should be used. Though, there is no mention *what* procedure it is. I would use `alter table ... move ...`

**Edit:** (thanks to @Jack Douglas):
Instead of `alter`, there is a `move_procedure` defined in `V$SYSAUX_OCCUPANTS` that should be used to move those occupants.

Comment: From SYSAUX? I'd advise against it.

Comment: -1 this is a very bad idea, don't do it. See [here](http://oracledocs.shu.ac.uk/oracle/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tspaces010.htm#sthref1221) for how to move Occupants out of the SYSAUX tablespace.

Comment: I also found this, but did not read it as carfeully, as I should :-) Now I see it :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you run this query and see lines with "ALL" then the link below could be causing your issue:

```
SELECT STATISTICS_NAME, SESSION_STATUS, SYSTEM_STATUS, ACTIVATION_LEVEL
 FROM v$statistics_level
 WHERE ACTIVATION_LEVEL = 'ALL'
 ORDER BY 3 ;
```

Look at the following blog post for the cause and solution to the issue:
[Why is my SYSAUX Tablespace so Big? Statistics_level=ALL](https://mwidlake.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/why-is-my-sysaux-tablespace-so-big-statistics_levelall/)

Comment: Please include the most important points from that post.  It may disappear, move to somewhere else, be stolen by aliens and so on - rendering your answer not that useful.