# SYSAUX tablespace is 98%

Tags: oracle

My SYSAUX tablespace is 98% full. In my tablespace statement `AUTOEXTENSIBLE=yes`.

So I want to know that will it add a new data file if it reaches 100% or if not then should I make makesize to unlimited?

Comment: this thread: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15790/reduce-size-of-sysaux might be of some use

Answer (score 3):

No, Oracle won't add an extra datafile.

Normally the SYSAUX tablespace is more or less stable so it would be smart to check what is eating the space in there. Connected as a DBA user, run the script `${ORACLE_HOME}/rdbms/admin/utlsyxsz` to get the current usage of the SYSAUX tablespace and see how it will grow when you change certain parameters for which you are asked to enter values.

See [Oracle® Database Administrator's Guide 11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tspaces010.htm) to get an idea of regular sizing.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure

- you have enough disk space available - check all mount points

  your files are allowed to autoextend in `dba_data_files`.

  next allocation size is not too big (important if you are getting closer to free space limit...)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle will not create a new datafile when the current one becomes full.

I suggest:

- Set the current datafile to `AUTOEXTEND`, but only up to a size
  smaller than the free space on the disk it resides on
- Create another datafile for the tablespace that can be used once the 1st datafile
  becomes full
- Pro-actively monitor the free space in the tablespace and the disk(s) the data files reside on

There may also be tables in the `SYSAUX` tablespace that can be purged. The most likely culprit is usually old AWR snapshots. You can query the `DBA_EXTENTS` data dictionary view (`group by SEGMENT_NAME`, filter on `TABLESPACE_NAME='SYSAUX'`) to get a better idea of why the tablespace is growing.